# Dart: Inherit method from abstract class

Tags: flutter, dart, abstract-class

Trying to make a generic route "base class", where an `abstract` class defines a getter that returns the route name. Something like this:

```dart
abstract class ScreenAbstract extends StatefulWidget {
  static String name;

  static String get routeName => '/$name';

  ScreenAbstract({Key key}) : super(key: key);
}
```

Then, any "screen" widget can extend this class:

```dart
class SomeScreen extends ScreenAbstract {
  static final name = 'someScreen';

  SomeScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SomeScreenState createState() => _SomeScreenState();
}
```

Which *should* then be accessible like this:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SomeScreen.routeName);
```

Hoever, when trying that, the linter throws an error:
`The getter 'routeName' isn't defined for the type 'SomeScreen'.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ScreenAbstract.routeName` is *static*. `static` members aren't inherited.  You will need to explicitly add a `SomeScreen.routeName` getter, or callers should use `ScreenAbstract.routeName` directly.

Comment: Gotcha. Can you show how to make it possible to call the getter from the extending class? (By making `ScreenAbstract.routeName` not static...)

Comment: You could let `ScreenAbstract.routeName` remain static and add `static String get routeName => ScreenAbstract.routeName;` to `SomeScreen`.

Comment: But that would mean that all classes that extend it will have the same value for `routeName`, No? Whereas I am trying to make it so that each "screen" class will have its own static `routeName` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In dart there's no inheritance of static members. See [Language Specification](https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.2.pdf) here-

> Inheritance of static methods has little utility in Dart. Static
> methods cannot be overridden. Any required static function can be
> obtained from its declaring library, and there is no need to bring it
> into scope via inheritance. Experience shows that developers are
> confused by the idea of inherited methods that are not instance
> methods.
>
> Of course, the entire notion of static methods is debatable, but it is
> retained here because so many programmers are familiar with it. Dart
> static methods may be seen as functions of the enclosing library.

To tackle this, you can update your solution like this -

Abstract Parent Class -

```
abstract class ScreenAbstract extends StatefulWidget {
  final String _name;
  String get routeName => '/$_name';
  ScreenAbstract(this._name, {Key key}) : super(key: key);
}
```

The Screen Widget that extends the Parent class -

```
class SomeScreen extends ScreenAbstract {  
  static final String name = "url";
  SomeScreen({Key key}) : super(name, key: key);

  @override
  _SomeScreenState createState() => _SomeScreenState();
}
```

Then you can access it like this  -

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SomeScreen().routeName);
```

Comment: Right, so basically, I cannot access it statically, but must use a class instance for that. Guess I'll just use an interface to enforce the implementation, rather than inherit the parent class. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, Interface would be the proper way to go about this.